# Converting a geometry point from GeoJSON to latitude and longitude

Tags: python, maps, gis, geopandas

I have a list containing GeoJSON objects like so:

```
{ 
    "type": "Feature", 
    "properties": { 
        "ListEntry": 1440052.000000, 
        "Name": "Edmonton War Memorial", 
        "Location": "Enfield, London, N9", 
        "Grade": "II",
        "ListDate": "2017\/01\/13",
        "AmendDate": null, 
        "LegacyUID": null,
        "NGR": "TQ3435693567",
        "CaptureSca": "1:1250", 
        "Easting": 534356.190450,
        "Northing": 193567.535720
    },
    "geometry": { 
        "type": "Point",
         "coordinates": [ 
             534356.190499999560416,
             193567.535700000822544 
          ]
    }
}
```

re the `geometry` key,  how does one convert the `coordinates` to a traditional latitude and longitude, ideally in Python?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not look like there is quite enough information in this entry alone to convert to latitude and longitude. For that, you'll also need the coordinate reference system of the points. But, supposing the geojson is saved in a file "points.json" and you know the epsg code corresponding to the coordinate reference system, you could do something like:

```
import geopandas as gp
gdf = gp.read_file("points.json")
epsg_code = 32630              # my guess based on a quick search, but evidently wrong
gdf.crs = {"init": "epsg:{}".format(epsg_code)}
gdf_reprojected = gdf.to_crs({"init": "epsg:4326"})
```

The points in `gdf_reprojected` would be in longitude/latitude.